# Noise in sending voice from android to PC over socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, voice

I'm trying to send voice from android to PC over sockets. My code is working but at PC end what I hear is lot of noise, I am even unable to listen to any voice.

Here is the android code that i'm using:

```
     byte buffer[]=new byte[1024];
     int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
         mic=new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
         mic.startRecording();
               
                  while(running){
                        count=mic.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        if(count>0){
                           OutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                  }
```

Here is PC Code:

```
    float sampleRate=44100;
    int sampleSize=16;
    int channel=1;
    boolean sign=true;
    boolean bigendian=true;
    AudioFormat format=new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSize, channel, sign, bigendian);
    
    SourceDataLine voiceLine;
    DataLine.Info LineInfo=new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    if(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(LineInfo)){
        System.out.println("Line Supported...");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not supported Line...");
    }
    voiceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(LineInfo);
    voiceLine.open(format);
    voiceLine.start();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());    
    while(true){
                 count=inputStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                 InputStream in;
                 in=new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
                 AudioInputStream ais=new AudioInputStream(in, format, buffer.length /format.getFrameSize());
                 ais.read(audio, 0, count);
                 voiceLine.write(audio, 0, count);
            }
```

What I test so far:

- Voice is clear when check with android to android.
- Voice is clear when i attach headphone to android phone.
- Voice is not clear without headphone attach to android phone(lot of noise).

What I have tried so far:

- Use less SAMPLE RATE(8000).
- Use UDP instead of TCP.
- Try different buffer size.

But got nothing.

Comment: Something is unclear. So voice is clear when you use a headphone and are sending from android to PC? And your problem is when you are not using headphones and are sending from android to PC?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by android to android? You transmit the same thing over BT to another android phone and are able to playback using similar code on the PC? The conditions under which you tested things are ambiguous.

Comment: Yes it's working using headphones. And yes sending from android to PC. For android to android i use receiver code(audioTrack class) which is not mentioned in question...

Comment: So since it works from android to PC, it would suggest the issue has to do with the microphone. Are you trying both Android to PC cases with the headset connected? Do you know which microphone the phone thinks is connected? You may need to try CAMCORDER instead of MIC.

Comment: I was try  CAMCORDER but same result.

Comment: This suggests that some other problem is going on. Android automatically adjusts the microphone source based on whether or not a headset is available. What is SAMPLE_RATE on the phone? The AudioRecord doc says " 44100Hz is currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself.

It turned out that I had to change it to `bigendian=false;`, and now it works.